# im using maven ,.java,sts eclipse and selenium ide, svn and web driver in ubuntu

Tags: java, maven, web, ubuntu-12.04, selenium-webdriver

i am using maven,java,sts eclipse and selenium ide, svn and web driver in ubuntu.i am new to these technologies. i need to know how to test my project(web site) via terminal using maven.
when i use this command **mvn clean test** . test and build will be succeed.. but test not run..
i use selenium ide to record it. and i covert that sample.java and save it in my project ..

```
sampath@sampathkumar-Breeze:~/svn/colorspace_swift/trunk/colorspace-swift$ mvn clean test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Colorspace Swift 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact easymock:easymock:jar:2.0 has been relocated to org.easymock:easymock:jar:2.0
[WARNING] The artifact jdbc:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0 has been relocated to javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ colorspace-swift ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/sampath/svn/colorspace_swift/trunk/colorspace-swift/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.1:run (default) @ colorspace-swift ---
[INFO] Executing tasks
    [mxmlc] Loading configuration file /usr/local/flex_sdk_4.0/frameworks/flex-config.xml
    [mxmlc] /home/sampath/svn/colorspace_swift/trunk/colorspace-swift/src/main/webapp/flex/color_card/BreezeCC.swf is up-to-date and does not have to be rebuilt.
     [copy] Copying 29 files to /home/sampath/svn/colorspace_swift/trunk/colorspace-swift/target/classes/html_messages
     [copy] Copying 12 files to /home/sampath/svn/colorspace_swift/trunk/colorspace-swift/target/classes/help_files
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ colorspace-swift ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 116 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:copy-resources (copy-prod-resources) @ colorspace-swift ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 32 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ colorspace-swift ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 566 source files to /home/sampath/svn/colorspace_swift/trunk/colorspace-swift/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ colorspace-swift ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/sampath/svn/colorspace_swift/trunk/colorspace-swift/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ colorspace-swift ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ colorspace-swift ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/sampath/svn/colorspace_swift/trunk/colorspace-swift/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.154s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 06 18:15:53 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/165M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------



no test run in project.. please help how to test in maven
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines from your log file suggests that you don't have your test sources in the right directory:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ colorspace-swift ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
```

Put all test sources in `src/test/java`. Then they will be built and `maven-surefire-plugin` will find them.